# Core Data working with subset of full data store...HOW?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm banging my head trying to figure out something in Core Data that I think should be simple to do, and I need some help.

I have a data store which contains data from the past two years, but in my app, I have certain criteria so that the user only works with a subset of that data (i.e. just the past month).  I have created the predicates to generate the fetch request and all that works fine.

My issue is that I then want to run some additional predicates on this subset of data (i.e. I just want objects with name=Sally).  I'd like to do so without having to re-run the original predicate with an additional predicate (in a NSCompoundPredicate); I'd rather just run it on the subset of data already created.

Can I just run a predicate on the fetch results?

Is the format of the predicate the same as for the initial calls into the core data store?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the original array of results using a predicate. See the NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate method.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I would consider doing what you're talking about is if you find that modifying the predicate at the FetchedResultsController level caused significant performance degradation.

My recommendation is to get a reference to your fetchedResultsController in your view controller and update your predicate with a compound predicate matching your additional search parameters.

If you were to tie your viewControllers data source to a predicate of a predicate you wouldn't be able to properly utilize the NSFetchedResultsControllers Delegate methods that allow for easy, dynamic updating of Views such as table view and collection view.

```
    /* assuming you're abstracting your datastore with a singleton */
    self.fetchedResultsController = [DataStore sharedStore].fetchedResultsController;  
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:yourPredicate];
```

Make sure to configure your fetch requests' batch size to a reasonable value to improve performance.